# iOS Swift - URLSession.dataTask doesn't call callback method after first invocation

Tags: ios, swift, networking, urlsession

I have the following swift code...

```
    public class WebAPI {
        private var session:URLSession

        public init() {
            session = URLSession.shared
        }

        public func makeCall(_ foo:String, callback:@escaping (String?)->Void) {
            var request:URLRequest = makeRequest()

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                var resp = makeResponse(data)        
                callback(resp)
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

I call the class method...

```
public class MyController : UIViewController {
    var api:WebAPI = WebAPI()

    func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        api.makeCall("blah") { (response) in
            print ("\(response)")
        }
    }
}
```

When I launch the UIViewController - the network request is made (via makeCall) and the callback that the MyController class passed in is called... As you would expect.

However when it is called again (eg if you switch tabbar tabs and come back) the network request is made (with no errors) however the callback for the session.dataTask(...) is never called.

Been stuck on this for a while now so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to put break point in print statement ? because your code looks okay to me and also add print statement on makeCall to print callback object and resp

Comment: and your method should be `override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` not `func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)`

Comment: Hi yes i have tried to put breakpoint - i am using override on viewwillappear.. syntax issue for the snippit ive created for stackoverflow!...

Comment: When i put breakpoint on the print("\(response") line it hits it the first time. 2nd time it doesnt.